# Searching through a database using checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, mysqli

Hi guys so i am trying to understand what the best way to search through a database using check boxes is. I am new to this and was looking at tutorials etc but cant seem to find anything which will help. I can make a search engine which searchs through my database and returns what i need but i dont get how to do it with checkboxes. For example:

My database contains this:

```
    MovieName: ...
    Gen1: ... 
    Gen2:... 
    Gen3:... 
    Gen4:... 
etc
```

Now like i said above i got it to work with a search box where the user can write a simple phase such as action and it will bring up the movies which has action in their genres but i got no idea how to do it with checkboxes.

HTML:

```
    <form action = "movie.php" method = "post">
        <input type="checkbox" name = "search" value="action" checked> Kale<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name= "search" value="comdey" checked> orange<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 

    <?php echo("$output");?>
```

My database name TestHere and table is called test. Any help on completing this matter or any advice would be great, if you would like to see my search function i could post that but i dont think it will help with the search function of the checkboxes

Comment: You probably need to change the name of the checkboxes to `name="search[]"` and treat them as an array of checked boxes in PHP.

Comment: @apokryfos i was thinking that but i am not exactly sure how 2 do it, would i be able to use my other search function and change that so it works with checkboxes?

Comment: Be aware that you are open to SQL injection - you should filter the $variables you pass into your query.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `mysql_` functions already. Time to move on to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: ah yes i do know all about that , but like i said above its just for me , its a project that i want to work on using the old functions for now and then using the new functions etc and comparing them

Comment: No. You won't compare anything. Security is everyone business; what will you do if your database is leaked with some "sensible users" ? Please, fix the SQL injection ASAP. Concerning PDO, yes, that's better; but if you wanna use a 10-years deprecated lib, that's yours.

Comment: @Lpu8er like i said , i know this and i have PDO version of this however like i said this is a project which i am working on and i want to do it this way? not sure why this is a problem , its for my own personal use

Comment: Don't misunderstand what I wrote. If you wanna use the mysql-C old API, that's YOUR business. But if you keep a SQL injection, that's a different matter. You can avoid this, even using mysql-C. Please, keep that in mind, fix your code then continue to @Ukuser32 's answer which seems a good start.

Comment: @Lpu8er ah yes i get u sorry :) in my other version i have done this dont worry but yes for this version 100% its awfull but its aright for now, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @apokryfos mentioned you need to do the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="genre1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="genre2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="genre3" />

Then in your PHP

<?php
$str = array();
$fields = array('gen1','gen2','gen3');
foreach ($_POST['genres'] as $genre){
    foreach ($fields as $gen){
        $str[] = "$gen LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($genre).'%"';
    }
}
$str = implode(' OR ',$str);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE movieName LIKE '%$searchq%' $str") or die("Could not search.");
?>
```

Its worth saying that although this should work LIKE is not the best search as it has to look through each string. In reality if the whole string is the Genre supplied you should use ='' which also allows for better indexing.

Comment: I am going to try this now, thanks for the input, 1 question those, my movies are all in divs etc and i want them to look that way , u can see how i outputed it above, would  that work here is well?

Comment: This bit comes before your DIV output area.

Comment: So i would take out the while loop etc?

Comment: No the above bits are to replace your existing $query and the input boxes go on the form - this will require a bit of reworking your existing code but I believe its the right direction.

Comment: thanks so much will try this now and see what i can do